# Python Class Issue

Tags: python, class, object, self

This code is giving me this error.

class Bank:

line 117, in Bank

```
main()
```

in main

```
format(z, '10.2f'), format(bank.MakeWithdrawal(self,amount)))
```

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'MakeWithdrawal'

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!!!!

```
class Bank:

    def __init__(self,incomingAcctNum,incomingBalance):
     self.__acctNum = incomingAcctNum
     self.__balance = incomingBalance
     self.__totalDeposits = 0
     self.__DepositCount = 0
     self.__totalWithdrawals = 0
     self.__WithdrawalCount = 0

    def MakeDeposit(self,amount):
     self.__balance = self.__balance + amount
     self.__totalDeposits = self.__totalDeposits + amount
     self.__DepositCount = self.__DepositCount + 1

    def MakeWithdrawal(self,amount):
     if (self.__balance >= amount):
        self.__balance = self.__balance - amount
        self.__totalDeposits = self.__totalDeposits + amount
        self.__DepositCount = self.__DepositCount + 1
        return True
    else:
        return False

    def DisplayBalance(self):
     self.__balance = self.__balance
     self.__totalDeposits = self.__totalDeposits
     self.__DepositCount = self.__DepositCount

    def getAcctNum(self):
     return self.__acctNum

    def getBalance(self):
     return self.__balance

     def getTotalDeposits(self):
      return self.__totalDeposits

    def getDepositCount(self):
     return self.__DepositCount

    def getTotalWithdrawals(self):
     return self.__totalWithdrawals

    def getWithdrawalCount(self):
     return self.__WithdrawalCount


   def main():

    a = input("Enter bank account ID #1: ")
    b = eval(input("Enter balance for bank account #1: "))
    c = input("Enter bank account ID #2: ")
    d = eval(input("Enter balance for bank account #2: "))




    infile = open("trans","r")
    x = (infile.readline().strip())
    y = (infile.readline().strip())
    z = eval(infile.readline())


    print()
    print(format("Acct", '15s'), format("Trans Type", '20s'),
          format("Amount", '15s'), format("Balance", '10s'))
    print("------------------------------------------------------------")

     while x != "X":

        bank = (z)


        if y == "W":
            print(format(x, '15s'), format("Withdrawal", '15s'),
                  format(z, '10.2f'), format(bank.MakeWithdrawal()))
        elif y == "D":
            print(format(x, '15s'), format("Deposit", '15s'),
                  format(z, '10.2f'), format(bank.MakeDeposit(self,amount)))
        else:
            print(format(x, '15s'), format("Balance", '25s'),
                  format(bank.DisplayBalance(self)))





        x = (infile.readline().strip())
        y = (infile.readline().strip())
        z = eval(infile.readline())
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
    print()
    print(format("ABC123, Deposits: ", '15s'))
    print(format("ABC123, Withdrawals: ", '15s'))
    print(format("ABC123, Ending Balance: ", '20s'))
    print()
    print(format("DEF456, Deposits: ", '15s'))
    print(format("DEF456, Withdrawals: ", '15s'))
    print(format("DEF456, Ending Balance: ", '20s'))



main()
```

Comment: `bank` is a float.

Comment: Make bank refer the class in consideration. You are assigning it a float value, instantiate it instead

Comment: Probably this line is the root cause:  z = eval(infile.readline())

Comment: z has a value of 10, 20, 30,  40, and 50

Comment: BTW, why do you think you need `eval` here? `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bank` in this case is a float, I don't think that is right.

`bank.MakeWithdrawal()` needs an amount to withdrawal. i.e `bank.MakeWithdrawal(amount)`
 in

```
if y == "W":
    print(format(x, '15s'), format("Withdrawal", '15s'),
              format(z, '10.2f'), format(bank.MakeWithdrawal()))
```

The same goes for `bank.Makedeposit()`. `bank.DisplayBalance()` doesn't need an input bank is the self when called. i.e. `bank.DisplayBalance()`
Also make sure that your indentatation is correct, I don't know if it is a copy/paste error or not, but it looks like your def main() is a method in the Bank class.

Answer (score 0):

You first say that `z` is a float by the line `z = eval(infile.readline())`.

Then you say that `bank` is `z` since `bank = (z)`.

Make `bank` an instance of `Bank` instead, possibly in a main loop outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

create an object of Bank class and call bank methods on it replace line `bank=(z)` with `bank=Bank(inComingAcctNum,incomingBalance)` .
and also keep main out of the class.

Comment: if I do that it says Bank is not defined

Comment: Please check declaration and scope of class where it definined and where it is being accessed.